# Elementary Inequality regarding Sum of Squares

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, inequality, sums-of-squares

\begin{align}
&\mbox{If}\quad
A = \sum_{i = 1}^{m}a_{i}\,x_{i}^{2}
\quad\mbox{and}\quad
B = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}b_{j}\,y_{j}^{2}
\\[2mm] &\
\mbox{where}\quad
x_{i}, y_{j}, a_{i}, b_{j} \geq 1, \quad x_{i} \neq y_{j}
\end{align}
Then, **find necessary and sufficient conditions such that** $A - B > 1$ when $m = n$ is *odd*, $\ A > B$.

**My Attempt:**

Because there are total $m = n\ $  subtractions $a_{i}\,x_{i}^{2} - b_{j}\,y_{j}^{2}$ and each
$a_{i}\,x_{i}^{2} - b_{j}y_{j}^{2} > 2$ ( minimum possible case is
$1 \cdot 2^{2} -  1\cdot 1^{1} = 3$ ),  we need to show  $\displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1}a_{i}\,x_{i}^{2} - b_{i}\,y_{i}^{2}$ has to be $\geq 0$.

so the sum of  $a_{i}\,x_{i}^{2} - b_{j}\,y_{j}^{2}$  is greater than $0$, thus $A - B > 1$.

Is there anything in the literature imply the proposition? In that case plz comment.

The post consider the non-trivial case, if any specification is required, plz let me know.

ADDED NOTE:

All $x_{i}, y_{j}, a_{i}, b_{j}$ are integers.

Is linear form of logarithm  relevant to this problem $?$.

Comment: I don't understand your question and example. Can you please reformulate?

Comment: @Vlad up-voting, then withdrawing vote, then down-voting ......whats up with you mate!! anyway, plz specifically comment which part is not clear.

Comment: Hello there. I usually upvote bountied questions just to give some encouragement and to "bring them to the front", but at second thought, I saw this is unreadable. I do not understand anything. For example, what does this mean: "and each $-2>a_ix_i^2-b_iy_i^2>2$". Not to mention this is mathematically absurd, it should be $-2<a_ix_i^2-b_iy_i^2<2$. How did you get that? Why do we need to show that a specific sum has to be $\geq 0$. I cannot even describe what I do not understand, because nothing in this is coeherent.

Comment: Interpreting your argument: "minimum possible case is $1 \cdot 2^{2} -  1\cdot 1^{2} = 3$": does that mean that the numbers  $x_{i}, y_{j}, a_{i}, b_{j} $ have to be **integers** ? (This is nowhere being specified). Otherwise, your case is not minimal, as you can construct your example much tighter as $1 \cdot (1+\epsilon)^{2} -  1\cdot 1^{2} = \epsilon^{2} + 2 \epsilon^{2}$ which can be made arbitrarily small.

Comment: @Andreas you are correct I have edited. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
&\mbox{If}\quad
A = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_{i}\,x_{i}^{2}
\quad\mbox{and}\quad
B = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}b_{j}\,y_{j}^{2}
\\[2mm]
\end{align}

with integer
$x_{i}, y_{j}, a_{i}, b_{j} \geq 1 , \quad x_{i} \neq y_{j} $, and $A > B$, we are to find conditions for which  $A-B > 1$.

As OP already posted, the  given condition $A > B$, together with the integer condition of the variables, implies that the difference $A - B$ cannot become arbitrarily small. So we start to investigate the smallest such difference under the given conditions.

This can be used to construct first of all an example where the assertion does not hold true.  Let $A = 1\cdot 3^2 = 9$ and $B = 2\cdot 2^2  = 8$, then $A>B$ and $A-B=1$ so the required $A-B>1$ fails. There are many more such examples possible for other integer numbers
$x_{i}, y_{j}, a_{i}, b_{j} \geq 1$. So, the only statement we can make in general is that, due to the integer condition and $A>B$, the minimum possible difference is  $A-B=1$.

From this it follows that it's difficult resp. unlikely to give general *explicit* conditions for making $A-B> 1$. Such conditions can  be  implicitely stated:   Choose integer numbers
$x_{i}, y_{j}, a_{i}, b_{j} \geq 1$ such that  $A-B\ge 2$. (Then $A-B > 1$ is obviously obtained.)

Comment: @ConsiderNon-TrivialCases I already did - I cannot upvote twice. Your question was not well writen: I also had to "interpret" your question first, see my comments above. I think once your question was "understood", it very much improved and is now an interesting question. I guess unfortunately the vote-downs occured before that process.